# Jenkins execute shell calabash-android: command not found

Tags: android, jenkins

I am trying to run Android automation code in my local Jenkins. Execution failing with this error.

Script run command:

```
calabash-android run /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Desktop/Android_Apps/app-dev-xxx.apk ./gherkin/pro/xxxxtest.feature -p common_requirements -p android -p UK_en_android_3dot4dot6 -p commonBranch_br_2015 -p envqa -p squidman --tags @done_android ADB_DEVICE_ARG=9151621e --format Cucumber::Formatter::CustomHtml -o ./test_reports/temp.html

Error: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson8798431523816454555.sh: line 4: calabash-android: command not found
```

I have verified the `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` variables by using `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and I am seeing correct paths in Jenkins console. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: How have you modified the env variables? Have you tried to execute the command as the user running Jenkins?

Comment: I have set the env variables in jenkins global settings. No I did not try that.